# explain why the line through A and B must intersect the line through C and D.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let A, B, C and D be four distinct points in 3-space. If ⃗⃗⃗⃗⃗ × ⃗⃗⃗⃗⃗ ≠ 0 and ⃗⃗⃗⃗⃗ . (⃗⃗⃗⃗⃗ × ⃗⃗⃗⃗⃗ ) = 0, explain why 
the line through A and B must intersect the line through C and D.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The condition that $AB \times CD \neq \mathbf{0}$ means that $AB$ and $CD$ are not parallel. The condition that $AC \cdot (AB \times CD)= 0$ implies that $AC, AB, CD$ are coplanar. So they lie in the same plane and are not parallel so this means.....